# sklearn: Turning off warnings

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, scikit-learn

When I'm fitting `sklearn`'s `LogisticRegression` using a 1 column python `pandas` `DataFrame` (not a `Series` object), I get this warning:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py:125:         
DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was 
expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using 
ravel().
y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
```

I know I could easily advert this warning in my code, but how can I turn off these warnings?

Comment: You can filter the warnings using the warning module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As posted [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings),

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    # Do stuff here
```

Thanks to Andreas above for posting the link.

Comment: import warnings

Comment: Note that this answer does also work within `joblib` threads. Other answers, i.e., setting a warning filter globally, does not work when `joblib` uses the `loky` backend which spawns separate processes for each task.

Comment: Actually @Tobias, that didn't work for me in that situation. But I found another solution that does. Just add `os.environ['PYTHONWARNINGS']='ignore::FutureWarning'` to your program (or set that env variable in another way), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72807161/1265409.

Answer (score 44):

You can use this:

```
import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import DataConversionWarning
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=DataConversionWarning)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.

Comment: @pirho OP probably already knows about the cause of the problem and explicitly mentions the desire to turn off the warning only instead of solving the "problem".

Comment: It is worth mentioning that one must `import warnings` as well.

Comment: how to disable Convergence Warnings, for example, for estimators that use sklearn's coordinate descent algorithm? Replacing **DataConversionWarning** with **ConvergenceWarning** in the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the warning tells you exactly what is the problem:

You pass a 2d array which happened to be in the form `(X, 1)`, but the method expects a 1d array and has to be in the form `(X, )`.

Moreover the warning tells you what to do to transform to the form you need: `y.ravel()`. So instead of suppressing a warning it is better to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: In case you want to ignore or get rid of such warning

```
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Otherwise if you're looking into the cause of the issue this might be helpful.

When you try to fit your model, make sure `X_test` and `y_test` are similar to those used in training data. in other words `X_train` and `X_test` should be the same with the same features and same for `X_test` and `y_test`

For example: `np.array(X_test)` is not same as `X_test`, given that `X_train` is just a numpy's `DataFrame` and `X_test` was splitted out from dataset:

```
# imports 
...
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2)    
# the following produce warning since X_test's shape is different than X_train
y_predicts  = clf.predict(np.array(X_test))
# no warning (both are same) 
y_predicts  = clf.predict(X_test)
```