# How to disable ConvergenceWarning using sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, warnings

I'm using GridSearchCV to optimize hyper-parameters for SVM. I set the maximum number of iterations because I can't wait several hours to get result. I know there will be convergence warnings. I just 
want to ignore these warnings and not show up in the terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 51):

This was a pain to track down, as all suggested answers I've seen simply do not work. What finally worked for me was in the example code [Early stopping of Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_early_stopping.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-sgd-early-stopping-py):

```
from sklearn.utils.testing import ignore_warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
```

You can then annotate a function like so:

```
@ignore_warnings(category=ConvergenceWarning)
def my_function():
    # Code that triggers the warning
```

Note that you need not directly import anything from `warnings`.

I think that's quite nice as it will only suppress warnings in the specific case where you need it, rather than globally.

Comment: Seems useful, however the function should probably be named something related to SVM since that is the method in the question.

Comment: Reasonable point, thanks. I've renamed it to make it clearer that it's just a generic example.

Comment: It just smells a bit importing `testing` code in production but .. well ...

Comment: what do you mean by *# Code that triggers the warning* in your function, could you make an explicit example to turn off the convergence warning when calculating estimators that use sklearn's coordinate descent algorithm?

Comment: Just note that 'sklearn.utils.testing' is deprecated since 0.22 and will be removed in 0.24. It seems that 'sklearn.utils._testing' (note the additional underscore) is the way to go now - see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_early_stopping.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-sgd-early-stopping-py

Comment: In 2021 the following works for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086398/sklearn-turning-off-warnings

Answer (score 45):

I will take a long shot here.

You have not provided enough information. You just mentioned that you're using `SVM` but not which type of `SVM` since there are many implementations of it such as `SVC`, `NuSVC` and `LinearSVC`. Those different types have different properties.

Why to care? because some of them support/accept executing jobs in **parallel** such as `LinearSVC` one!

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning)
```

The above code (or the other variants of it) should do the job, but if it is running in parallel, it will only do in the very first run/iteration ( I am not pretty sure why but it seems every job has its own Pythonic configuration as if it is a new instance or something!)

---

Also, you mentioned that you are using `GridSearchCV` which has `n_job` parameter as well. Its `Scikit` Documentation says:

> Number of jobs to run in parallel. None means 1 unless in a
>   joblib.parallel_backend context. -1 means using all processors

`joblib.parallel_backend` means what number of jobs is set in the estimator or any per-defined configurations.

---

### Summary

Running jobs in parallel can be the reason of not suppressing the warnings. More information from OP is required.

---

### EDIT

I checked it again, and indeed, using `GridSearchCV` with `scikit-learn` version **0.20.3** and **low** `max_iter` **while suppressing warnings**, lead to the following results:

1. `SVC or LinearSVC` + `GridSearchCV(n_jobs=-1 or >1)`: *Failed* to suppress warnings.
2. `SVC  or LinearSVC` + `GridSearchCV(n_jobs=None or 1)`: *Succeeded* in suppressing warnings.
3. `LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1, solver='sag')` + `GridSearchCV(n_jobs=None or 1 or >1 or -1)`: *Failed* to suppress warnings.
4. `LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, solver='sag')` + `GridSearchCV(n_jobs=-1 or >1)`: *Failed* to suppress warnings.
5. `LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, solver='sag')` + `GridSearchCV(n_jobs=None or 1)`: *Succeeded* in suppressing warnings.

As you can see, if the estimator supports multi-jobs, setting `n_jobs=-1 or >1` will not suppress warnings regardless of `n_jobs` in `GridSearchCV`. On the other hand, if the estimator does not support multi-jobs, setting `n_jobs=-1 or >1` in `GridSearchCV` will not make warnings suppression work, however, setting `n_jobs=None or 1` will do make it work.

**Important Note**

That is what I found with `scikit-learn` version **0.20.3**, nevertheless, I tried it on my other laptop with `scikit-learn` version **0.19.2** and suppressing warnings worked all times regardless! I checked `scikit-learn` GitHub repository and noticed some commits about `joblib` since version 0.19.2 but I am not sure if there was a real change/update that caused the above behavior! You may want to open a ticket there and refer to the above results.

---

### UPDATE

The only way I could suppress all `Scikit-learn` warnings, is by issuing the following code at the beginning of the module. (but note that will suppress all warnings including yours - I needed that because I have logs saved to database):

```
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    os.environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = "ignore" # Also affect subprocesses
```

Comment: Excellent find with the `n_jobs` and parallel processing, had me stumped.

Comment: Great answer! This was the only answer which helped suppressing warnings with `RandomizedSearchCV` and `GridSearchCV` with `njobs>1`! To specifically disable warnings, I changed the last line to: `os.environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = ('ignore::UserWarning,ignore::ConvergenceWarning,ignore::RuntimeWarning')`. Specifying the module to ignore warnings from is also a nice addition: ` `os.environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = 'ignore::ConvergenceWarning:sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV'`

Comment: I like this one better because you can capture the warning and log it in your cv_results_ dictionary or reports.   Use with warnings.catch_warnings() as w:  (and then add w to your results

Answer (score 35):

In order to control Python warnings you can use the **warnings library**.
See detailed [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html).
So you can use [warning.simplefilter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) method as follows:

```
from warnings import simplefilter
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
simplefilter("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning)
```

Comment: This doesn't affect other warnings. It is better. I am having a similar problems with Bayesian Gaussian Mixtures. The code enter in a loop. I think it can be an Spyder bug (only restarting Spyder is possible to run again). The last warning is from SpyderKernelApp:

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: I tried this, and also warnings.simplefilter("ignore"), warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning). No good.

Comment: Are you running it on a Terminal?

Comment: Yes, I also use "-W ignore" when I run in terminal

Comment: I once a disabled an annoying warning by changing the source code, maybe give that a try.

Comment: Worked for me in JupyterLab. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```py
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
ConvergenceWarning('ignore')
```

Comment: Didn't work in PyCharm. The decorator method (1st answer) worked for me.