# How to capture specific warning without raising error in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, convergence

I am running different sets of data to identify best modeling algorithm for each dataset. I loop through each datasets to check various algorithms and select the best models based on test score. I know that some of my datasets not going to converge for specific models (i.e: LogisticRegression)
and getting converging warning (i.e:"lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):"). I don't want to ignore the warning. My goal is to return score for models that converge and don't return any value if I get this convergence warning.

I am able to work around this by turning this warning into error using "warnings.filterwarnings('error',category=ConvergenceWarning, module='sklearn')" and then go through try and except to get what I want. The problem with this method is that if there is any other error beside sklearn convergance warning it will bypass the try line and I wouldn't be able to know what cause the error. Is there any other way to capture this warning beside turning it to error?

Here is the simplified overview of my code ( data not included as its a big datasets and I don't think is relevant to the question). Most of stackoverflow questions that I was able to find is about how to supress the error([How to disable ConvergenceWarning using sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784971/how-to-disable-convergencewarning-using-sklearn))or to turn this warning into error and I didn't find any other method to capture the warning without turning it to error.

```
  from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
  from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
  warnings.filterwarnings('error',category=ConvergenceWarning, module='sklearn')
  try:
      model=LogisticRegression().fit(x_train,y_train)
      predict=model.predict(x_test)
  except:
      print('model didnt converge')
```

Comment: Just add a `raise` to your `except` block. Also you probably want `except Exception:` and not just a bare `except:`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean to use something like   "except ConvergenceWarning" and use else: with raise to still get other errors? if so, what is the advantage of adding raise? I do agree with except Exception ( something that I learned now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that can help you here.

First, you can specify what kind of Exception you are looking for, any you can specify multiple `except` clauses.  Here is an example from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

```py
import sys

try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except OSError as err:
    print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
except ValueError:
    print("Could not convert data to an integer.")
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

The other thing to notice in the above is the `except OSError as err`.  Using this syntax, you can print the error message associated with the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer and sharing the documents.