# python sklearn: suppress ConvergenceWarning n_job=-1

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I notice some people fail to suppress sklearn warnings even with warnings handling. Interestingly, I experience a similar scenario only when `n_job=-1`.

Warning suppression works fine when `n_job=1`. Is there a way for `n_job=-1`?

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.linear_model
import sklearn.model_selection

from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=ConvergenceWarning)

clf = sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet(max_iter=1000000)

grid = {'alpha': np.logspace(-5, 0, 25), 'l1_ratio': np.logspace(-5, 0, 25)}
grid_search = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
grid_search.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable ConvergenceWarning using sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784971/how-to-disable-convergencewarning-using-sklearn)

Comment: Please, tell me if my answer solved your issue or if you have found another way for suppressing the warning with `n_jobs = -1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with HalvinRandomSearch and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55595680/3637014) solved the problem.

I tried to specify the module to ignore as suggest in one of the comments below with `"ignore::UserWarning:sklearn"` but it doesn't work so I just ignore all `UserWarning`:

```
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    os.environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = "ignore::UserWarning"
```