# Supressing warnings during parallel execution with joblib in Python

Tags: python, warnings, joblib

I am using a function that generates a warning that I really don't need to read. The problem is that I want to run the function in parallel and when doing so, it seems I can not suppress warnings anymore. Consider this example:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def test(a, b):
    if a * b > 10:
        warnings.warn("You are being warned!!")
    return(a*b)

ii = np.arange(5)
jj = ii + 1

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    with Parallel(n_jobs=4) as parallel:
        result = parallel(delayed(test)(i, j) for i, j in zip(ii, jj))
```

This still produces the warning message... Please also be aware that in my case I can not rewrite the function `test` as it is imported from another package. Is there any way to not get the warning message?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is very annoying!

The default `joblib` backend spawns additional processes, which do not seem to inherit the warning filters applied using `warnings.filterwarnings`. However, you can use the [`PYTHONWARNINGS`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS) environment variable to set warning filters; this will affect all newly-spawned processes, which inherit their environment variables from those in the main process.

From the [relevant documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters):

> The warnings filter is initialized by `-W` options passed to the Python interpreter command line and the `PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable. The interpreter saves the arguments for all supplied entries without interpretation in `sys.warnoptions`; the `warnings` module parses these when it is first imported (invalid options are ignored, after printing a message to `sys.stderr`).
>
> Individual warnings filters are specified as a sequence of fields separated by colons:
>
> `action:message:category:module:line`

A [separate page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-filter) describes in more detail what each of these fields means, but basically:

- `action` describes what to do with the warning; for you, you want `ignore` to suppress the message
- `message` can be a string that must match the beginning of the warning message in order for it to be filtered
- `category` is the warning class, e.g. `FutureWarning`, `DeprecationWarning`
- `module` and `line` refer to where the warning is raised

Any of these fields can be empty, and you can leave off the trailing semicolons.

So, to ignore all `FutureWarning`s:

Within a Jupyter notebook, you can do something like

```
%env PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore::FutureWarning
```

Or in a script, add an entry to [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ):

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONWARNINGS']='ignore::FutureWarning'
```

It seems there should probably be a way to set environment variables only for the spawned process, but I can't figure out if `joblib` exposes an API for this.

Comment: To ignore all warnings, you should set the environment variable to `"ignore"`: `os.environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = "ignore"`.

Comment: Solution from @BiBi is working for me. Please, update your answer.